# Formula in R: how to use them in a generic fashion?

Tags: r, formula

Is there any way to use formulas in a generic fashion (without parsing) in R? I'd like to call functions from some packages that are using formula into home-made functions, possibly nested in other home-made functions.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do, with the `survey` package (taken from the documentation):

```
   library('survey')

   data(api)     
   dclus1 <- svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
   svymean(~api00, dclus1, deff=TRUE)
```

I'd like to replace the `~api00` by something more generic. There are ways to do so by parsing an expression (which I found utterly ugly), but it is not robust enough, particularly in 'nested' functions. Let say that I'd like to have something like:

```
func1 <- function(myvar, dclus) {
    return(func2(myvar, dclus))
}
```

with

```
func2 <- function(var, dclus) {
    return(svymean(~var, dclus))
}
```

If I do something like:

```
func2 <- function(var, dclus) {
    return(eval(parse(text=paste("svymean(~", var, ", ", 
           deparse(substitute(dclus), ")", sep=""))
}
```

it will work if I call directly `func2`, but it won't if I call `func1`, since it will get `myvar` instead of the variable I am actually trying to access. So it is not really usable the way I want anyway.

Is there any proper way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can try `as.formula(paste0("~",var))` to create your formula inside the `svymean` function

Comment: Or `as.formula(sprintf("~ %s", var))`, which is more convenient for more complicated formulas.

Comment: It did the trick, thanks. And it is neater than a wild `eval`!